# Problems in Asterisk when configuring x-lite

Tags: linux, asterisk, freepbx

I setup  [AsteriskNOW 1.6](http://www.asterisk.org/asterisknow/) with [freePbx](http://www.freepbx.org/).  I assigned it an address 192.168.164.128, and I made a team on a virtual machine (vmware).

There are 2 clients:

- Windows XP
- the AsteriskNOW server

I logged into the control panel and added an extension account, then when I log into [x-lite](http://www.counterpath.com/x-lite.html) to register that account, it did not connect. It showed me an error message like "connection failed, bad path" or something like that.

When I issue the command

```
show sip peers
```

on AsteriskNOW it told me this was an incorrect command.

I don't know where the problem is. Is there a configuration for 2 nodes "network configration" like a gateway or dns?

Comment: Do you set the correct port (5060) to connect in x-lite? It is hard to tell, where the problem is, maybe you should to try a different client, SJPhone instead on X-lite for example

Answer (score 0):

Check that you can reach the asterisk IP address from the PC you use for x-lite and that the port 5060 is not blocked by firewall.

Command for checking SIP registrations is:

```
sip show peers
```

see the [documentation](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Registering+Phones+to+Asterisk).